# jQuery "queue" (ajaxQueue plugin) - how to clear?

Tags: jquery

There is a useful plugin that Corey Frang posted on stackoverflow for queueing ajax requests. In my case, it's useful for loading up large collections of data in "chunks" so as to minimise user perceived slowness. It works perfectly, except when a pagination event is triggered before the queue of ajax requests has completed, in this case, the container holding the loaded objects will clear, but the queued requests will continue to run, resulting in undesired behaviour. What I would like is to find / learn of a way to clear the queue of all existing requests. The developer posted a way  to do this, however, it doesn't appear to work. I've tried reading up on .queue on the jQuery site, but I can't seem to understand how to make this work. I have already spent a lot of time trying to figure out this problem, but perhaps my lack of familiarity with some of the more complex aspects of jQuery is holding me back. Hope that someone out there who is more familiar with jQuery can help :)  ( marked what was suggested and does not appear to work with some "!!!!!" )

```
/*
* jQuery.ajaxQueue - A queue for ajax requests
* 
* (c) 2011 Corey Frang
* Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
*
* Requires jQuery 1.5+
*/ 
(function($) {

// jQuery on an empty object, we are going to use this as our Queue
var ajaxQueue = $({});

$.ajaxQueue = function( ajaxOpts ) {
    var jqXHR,
        dfd = $.Deferred(),
        promise = dfd.promise();

    // queue our ajax request
    ajaxQueue.queue( doRequest );

    // add the abort method
    promise.abort = function( statusText ) {

        // proxy abort to the jqXHR if it is active
        if ( jqXHR ) {
            return jqXHR.abort( statusText );
        }

        // if there wasn't already a jqXHR we need to remove from queue
        var queue = ajaxQueue.queue(),
            index = $.inArray( doRequest, queue );

        if ( index > -1 ) {
            queue.splice( index, 1 );
        }

        // and then reject the deferred
        dfd.rejectWith( ajaxOpts.context || ajaxOpts,
            [ promise, statusText, "" ] );

        return promise;
    };

    // run the actual query
    function doRequest( next ) {        
        jqXHR = $.ajax( ajaxOpts )
            .then( next, next )
            .done( dfd.resolve )
            .fail( dfd.reject );
    }

    return promise;
};

// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
// this is what the developer suggested on his website in the comments section
// ... but it does not appear to work
$.ajaxQueue.stop = function( clear ) { ajaxQueue.stop( clear ); }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: in this case, the .... ?

Comment: my bad guys - accidentally hit the "enter" key when entering tags, posted the rest now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank for your efforts in helping me to solve the problem. However..

I have found a better ajax queue plugin - "ajaxq" by Oleg Podolsky, if you need to queue ajax requests (along with the ability to properly clear the queue), I recommend using this instead.

Add to Queue:

```
ajaxq('queue_name', {
    // standard $.ajax options
});
```

Stop / Clear Queue:

```
ajaxq('queue_name');
```

Plugin:

```
/*
 * jQuery AjaxQ - AJAX request queueing for jQuery
 *
 * Version: 0.0.1
 * Date: July 22, 2008
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008 Oleg Podolsky (oleg.podolsky@gmail.com)
 * Licensed under the MIT (MIT-LICENSE.txt) license.
 *
 * http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajaxq
 * http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ajaxq/
 */

jQuery.ajaxq = function (queue, options)
{
    // Initialize storage for request queues if it's not initialized yet
    if (typeof document.ajaxq == "undefined") document.ajaxq = {q:{}, r:null};

    // Initialize current queue if it's not initialized yet
    if (typeof document.ajaxq.q[queue] == "undefined") document.ajaxq.q[queue] = [];

    if (typeof options != "undefined") // Request settings are given, enqueue the new request
    {
        // Copy the original options, because options.complete is going to be overridden

        var optionsCopy = {};
        for (var o in options) optionsCopy[o] = options[o];
        options = optionsCopy;

        // Override the original callback

        var originalCompleteCallback = options.complete;

        options.complete = function (request, status)
        {
            // Dequeue the current request
            document.ajaxq.q[queue].shift ();
            document.ajaxq.r = null;

            // Run the original callback
            if (originalCompleteCallback) originalCompleteCallback (request, status);

            // Run the next request from the queue
            if (document.ajaxq.q[queue].length > 0) document.ajaxq.r = jQuery.ajax (document.ajaxq.q[queue][0]);
        };

        // Enqueue the request
        document.ajaxq.q[queue].push (options);

        // Also, if no request is currently running, start it
        if (document.ajaxq.q[queue].length == 1) document.ajaxq.r = jQuery.ajax (options);
    }
    else // No request settings are given, stop current request and clear the queue
    {
        if (document.ajaxq.r)
        {
            document.ajaxq.r.abort ();
            document.ajaxq.r = null;
        }

        document.ajaxq.q[queue] = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a hint on how to cancel the queue with this plugin? thanks

Answer (score 1):

from what I see the problem seems to be:

```
var ajaxQueue = $({});
```

ajaxQueue is just an empty object, to stop using the object you need to point it to the jQuery plugin

```
ajaxQueue.stop = function( clear ) { $.ajaxQueue.stop( clear ); }
```

, or just use:

```
$.ajaxQueue.stop( clear );
```

Comment: the "just use" part you suggested works great.. no idea why I had such a hard time with this, but thank you so much :)

Comment: hmm - I've awarded the bounty, but I should note that this solution actually does not work (returns "no method" error). I'll post the solution when I'm able to find it.

Comment: please let me know why this worked first time and after 2 min is not working. Maybe I can help some more, and I think you can undo the bounty

Comment: cannot undo the bounty... it "worked" because it stopped the queue, but that's only because it produced a javascript error (i didn't check the console in my excitement, heh). So basically, it never worked :)

Comment: can you make ajax requests with jsfiddle? I'll check to see if you can, if possible, will put the fiddle up. Removing the "answered checkmark" for now to perhaps get more interest, but of course I'll put it back once it's solved. Cheers,

Comment: on second thought, I'll just create a new question with the jsfiddle and post the link here.. I'm semi-new to stackoverflow, hopefully that is OK with them

Answer (score 1):

I added this function to the `ajaxQueue` code. It may not be efficient but it does the job by clearing the queue:

```
if (ajaxOpts=='clear'){
    ajaxQueue.clearQueue();
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: this does not appear to work (just tried it), I'll try and get a fiddle up soon, but thank you very much for the answer attempt :)